# String internment in Python during JSON and XML parsing

Tags: python, string, deserialization, json-deserialization, xml-deserialization

Does Python perform string internment to save memory on duplicate keys when deserializing large arrays of dicts read from XML/JSON serialized to disk? (e.g. during `xml.dom.minidom.parse` / `json.load`)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/what-determines-which-strings-are-interned-and-when

Comment: What did you find out when you tried it?

Comment: I haven't done proper testing yet, but deserializing a wiktionary dump which contains a ton of identical keys seems to take a lot of time (and seemingly memory). I will try to do some proper tests by using string internment statistics from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039156/how-to-determine-the-number-of-interned-strings-in-python-2-7-5

But I hoped maybe someone knows specifically about internment of key names for JSON/XML serialization as they tend to contain a lot of identical strings. Maybe deserializers have their own string caches/pools? That would be interesting to know!

Comment: According to https://towardsdatascience.com/optimization-in-python-interning-805be5e9fd3e, things like json/xml keys are very likely to be interned, but it would be nice to know for sure

Comment: If you can use `xml.entree.ElementTree`, there is a `iterparse()` function with `clear()` after proceed the node, to save memory.